# How to show media only to owners?

Tags: 8, media

In order to allow users to add a remote video from Youtube, I am using the media type in a custom content type.

When users create a node of that content type, and add a media, they get a list that includes the media created by other users. I need that users see only the media they created, when creating a new node.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Should the media list be restricted always, even when viewing content, or only when creating content? Should users see other people's published videos? I'm guessing you'll need to restrict Media access with some Content access module. You can also look into Entity browser for a super charged design around entity reference field widgets.

Comment: @prkos From the question. I take the users who add a media to a node they are creating should only be able to select the media they created.